# Android Class Not Found Intermitten and Spreading Through The Code

Tags: java, android, kotlin, dalvik, android-multidex

It's been a week since I start my project using Kotlin and Android Studio. Everything seems ok until I started to get error

```
Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: android.support.v7.appcompat.R$drawable
```

the problem is, this error is intermittent and unclear for me.

I encountered this problem first time when my google play service enabled. The class not found was a resources from google service. After I looked at stack overflow, I found out it was about multidex (I hope it was that simple)

After I turned multidex on, it worked. But then the error occurred again until I turn off the google service. It work until another error occurred. After google service was turned off, the missing class now is fabric class (I'm also using fabric). Then I took out all fabric library.

Now the missing class is support.v7.appcompat.R$drawable. Weird thing is, whenever I do clean build on my project, the project smoothly. After some build, the ClassNotFoundException occurred again.

I know this problem was about the class is gone from the dex file. Multidex should solve it. But still, it still occurred. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Did you change your target at any time ? A pre-lollipop device require to add the dependency, contrary to V21+.

Comment: @GeoffreyMarizy thanks for the response, my minimum SDK target is API 14 and my SDK target is 24. It was 25. Because of this problem, I changed it to 24 because I think maybe API 25 is not stable. But the problem still there. What dependency do you mean? multidex dependency?

Comment: @GeoffreyMarizy do you think this problem is related to Kotlin? I'm experienced enough with Android and never met this problem before. This is my first time creating app using full Kotlin and this problem happens

Comment: Looks like more related to android than kotlin. I suspect Multidex to be not correctly working. Multidex support for lollipop or previous versions is different. Since you are targeting API 14 you should have compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1' in your dependencies. See https://developer.android.com/studio/build/multidex.html

Comment: after I update to the lastest android studio (version 3 canary 3) and upgrade the gradle to alpha-3, the problem is gone thankyou all